# fetch X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages response headers using php curl request

Tags: php, wordpress, api, curl

I'm trying to read the X-WP-* headers using a curl response requested on the WordPress API for fetching posts (See reference:https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/pagination/) e.g https://news.harvard.edu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts.
however I'm unable to read the http response headers returned.

```
        $url = "https://news.harvard.edu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
        $headers = [];
        $data=[];
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0); 
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
            function ($curl, $header) use (&$headers) {
                $len = strlen($header);
                $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
                if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
                    return $len;

                $headers[strtolower(trim($header[0]))][] = trim($header[1]);

                return $len;
            }
        );
        $response = curl_exec($curl);

        if ($response == false) {
            if(curl_errno($curl)>=1){
                $error = curl_errno($curl);
                curl_close($curl);
                $data = ["curl_error"=>$error];
            }
        }else{
            
            $data = [
                "headers"=>$headers
            ];

            curl_close($curl);
        }

        var_dump($data);     
        
// $data doesn't contain X-WP-Total and X-WP-TotalPages
```

Answer (score 0):

You were nearly there with the above but it lacks any SSL support which is why I believe it was failing. If you set the `CURLOPT_HEADER=true` option (as above) this code will still work but you'll not be able to decode the JSON response - you do not need to actually print the headers so set this as false or omit completely.

```
$url = "https://news.harvard.edu/wp-json/wp/v2/posts";
$cacert='c:/wwwroot/cacert.pem';
/*
    Download a copy of CACERT.pem from
    https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html
    
    save to webserver and modify the $cacert variable
    to suit - ensuring that the path you choose is
    readable.
*/


$headers = [];
$data=[];


# slightly modified version of original function
# only appends matching headers to output variable.
$callback=function( $ch, $header ){
    global $headers;
    
    $len = strlen( $header );
    $header = explode(':', $header, 2 );
    if( count( $header ) < 2 ) return $len;
    
    $param = strtolower( trim( $header[0] ) );
    $value = trim( $header[1] );
    
    if( strstr( $param, 'x-wp' ) ) $headers[ $param ]=$value;
    return $len;
};      



$curl=curl_init();
# The request will fail without including options for dealing with SSL.
if( parse_url( $url, PHP_URL_SCHEME )=='https' ){
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cacert );
}
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim( $url ) );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0 ); 
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

# we do not need the header in the output
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false );
# but we do need to process request headers - find any X-WP* headers
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, $callback );

$res = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close( $curl );

# process the required headers... 
printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', print_r( $headers, true ) );

$json=json_decode( $res );
# do stuff with JSON data
```

This outputs the following:

```
Array
(
    [x-wp-total] => 25118
    [x-wp-totalpages] => 2512
)
```